# Eclipse Luna, can't UPDATE TO HEAD

Tags: eclipse, svn, salesforce

I recently installed Eclipse Luna, when I right click on my `FORCE.COM` project, I can no longer find the option to `UPDATE TO HEAD`.

Am I missing a plugin or some configuration step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems as a subversion plugin is missing. I would recommend installing Subversive through the eclipse marketplace. Afterwards you have to install a SVN connector, you should choose SVNKit.